# How to append on didSelectRow and remove on didDeselectRow in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

I am trying to make a function that will append a selected row to an array and also remove from array when the row is deselected. Can you guys help me out with this?

**Select Row Function:**

```
var exercises = [exercise]() // Array that will be filled by selected rows

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? exerciseCell
   let exercisesSelected = selectedCell?.exerciseNameLbl.text
    exercisenames.insert(exercisesSelected!, at: 0)
}
```

**This is my deselect Delegate method:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? exerciseCell

        if exercisenames.count < 1 {
            print("empty array")
        }else{
        exercisenames.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        print(exercisenames)
        }
    }
```

Looking forward for any help, thank you!

Kevin.

Comment: There is another delegate method `deselectRowAtIndexPath:`. You can remove it from array there.

Comment: It isn't really clear what you are asking...usually you add/remove objects from an array of data (data that you will represent with a cell). So, are you asking to move an object from an array to another based on the actions? In that case, you can use the answer of @New16, but your code is wrong btw.

Comment: Actually it is clear that from that he wants to remove the object on deselection. So, that delegate should handle it.

Comment: @New16 Hi new16, i have edited the question. I hope this helps you a bit more

Comment: @New16 I would like to add an item to the array when selecting a row. And when I click the same row again, it deselect it and it has to remove that item that recently has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for in` loop to remove a specific object in the array.

```
for (index,value) in exercisenames.enumerate() {
    if value == selectedCell.exerciseNameLbl.text {
        exercisenames.remove(at:index)
    }
}
```

Comment: @KevinVugts No problem :) I suggest you read through the Swift guide carefully, it helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

u can use only one delegate func for it, like this:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if exercisenames.count < 1 {
        print("empty array")
    } else {

      //check if exercise exist in array
      if exercisenames.contain(/*your exercise*/) == true {
           exercisenames.remove(at: indexPath.row)
           tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
     } else {
        //insert to array
     }
    }

}
```

mb this helps u)